# jQuery get AJAX data each not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get each `name` and `logo` out of my returned data, but I cannot. The issue could be that the value of JSON comes out of the database and is escaped too.

How can I get each `name` and `logo` from the data I posted below?

Code:

```
$.getJSON('/sms/fetch_smartpages/', function (data) {
    var items = [];

    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        $('#linkHolder').append('<p>' + val + '</p>');

        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.fields.JASON.NAME + '</li>');
    });
});
```

This is the data as it comes back:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 11,
        "model": "content",
        "fields": {
            "logo": "",
            "json": "{\"name\":\"sas\",\"logo\":\"\",\"theme\":\"a\",\"pages\":[{\"id\":\"1366993986180\",\"name\":\"Page Name\",\"type\":\"basic\",\"components\":{\"img\":\"\",\"text\":\"\"}}]}",
            "link": null,
            "name": "sas",
            "user": 2
        }
    },


    {
        "pk": 18,
        "model": "content",
        "fields": {
            "logo": "",
            "json": "{\"name\":\"test123456789\",\"logo\":\"\",\"theme\":\"e\",\"pages\":[{\"id\":\"1366994946585\",\"name\":\"Page Name\",\"type\":\"basic\",\"components\":{\"img\":\"\",\"text\":\"\"}}]}",
            "link": 18,
            "name": "test123456789",
            "user": 2
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: There certainly is no `val.fields.JASON.NAME` in that json. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.each(data, function (index, val) {

      items.push('<li id="' + index+ '">' + val.fields.name + '</li>');


    });
```

Comment: gives me index is not defined

Comment: What should val[index] be?

Comment: cool that worked, but can I ask a question: why was it not  val.json.fields.name?

Comment: is called that in the DB cannot change it :(

Comment: because you are accessing your value with val .In that we have fields

Answer (score 1):

Try this but not tested

```
items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.fields.name + '</li>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, try using the parseJSON function to create a dictionary. Then you can get name and logo like a normal field.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `json` element of `val.fields` actually is a string, not a json object. So `val.fields.json.name` will not work, as `val.fields.json` is not a json object. You either have to fix the server so it returns a proper json object at this location, or you need to parse that particular fields to JSON.

**Edit**

However, it appears that `name` and `logo` also are set directly to `var.fields`, so `var.fields.name` and `var.fields.logo` should work.

Comment: it does work as you stated, what I'm confused about is now its get set to fields?

Comment: Probably set on the server somehow. Hard to say without more knowledge about what happens at the other end.